# Getting the following error while executing expo init command

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

```
Installing dependencies...
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/expo/react-native-maps.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-01T08_16_06_470Z-debug.log
Process exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure, that you have [git installed](https://hackernoon.com/install-git-on-windows-9acf2a1944f0). NPM requires git for installing some of the packages. You can check if git is installed via:

```sh
git --version
```

If so, according to the [reported issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/282), removing and reinstalling node_modules should help:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

You can also try to resolve the issue with [yarn](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/236):

```sh
brew install yarn
npm uninstall -g create-react-native-app
yarn global add create-react-native-app
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a `core-js` version issue.

In `package.json`, check `"expo-core": "version"` and if it is lower than the error:You correct the version to fit the error.

and `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

or

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Once you've done it, try running a new `expo init`.

Answer (score 1):

Just check that you've git installed on your system. otherwise, download it

Install git from here - https://git-scm.com/downloads

Your problem will be solved cheers! :)

Comment: Checking for git and if not present installing it is already given as suggestion in the answer from April 1st [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55451212/6707985) including a link to installation instructions. Please only add answers that brings new suggestions in.

Answer (score 0):

The default `expo-template-blank` template points `react-native` to their own Github repo - installing from a Github repo might cause the NPM to hang or err out for various reasons.

To work around this `ctrl-c` to interrupt initialization when it proceeds to install the dependencies after the project scaffolding is done, edit the `package.json` to install `react-native` from the NPM registry - for example this is how my dependencies look:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.10"
//...
```

Then manually do `npm i` to install the dependencies and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

This shows when you dont have git installed. 
You can follow any of the answers above to get it working on local. 
But if you're facing this issue in deploying a node app, check the node image you're using for deployment. If it is node: alpine then u will get this error.

To fix it, you can use node:carbon image.