# npm install shows error with git not found

Tags: node.js, angular, git, npm, angular7

I have recently added some dependencies to the package JSON and tried installing npm, but it shows errors related to git not found:

> npm ERR! path git
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall spawn git
> npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
> npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t
> ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
> npm ERR! enoent
> npm ERR! enoent
> npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

[image]

Comment: Do you have git installed ? The error is from `undefined ls-remote` which should be `git ls-remote`

Comment: is it essential to install git?

Comment: Yes, you need to have git installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the following error while executing expo init command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450764/getting-the-following-error-while-executing-expo-init-command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+npm+ERR%21+enoent+undefined+ls-remote

Comment: Also make sure "run command prompt as administrator". This worked for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to [install](https://git-scm.com/downloads) `git` in your machine to have it working.

```
undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
```

it should have been

```
git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
```

There is error related to git path. [check this ls-remote command](https://riptutorial.com/git/example/1486/ls-remote)

Comment: I tried the same > git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git command. After reruning yarn producing below error..

Comment: warning Pattern ["file-saver@eligrey/FileSaver.js#1.3.8"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "C:\\Users\\[xyz]\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v1\
pm-file-saver-2.0.5-cea522bc41bfadc364" as pattern ["file-saver@github:eligrey/FileSaver.js"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
Directory: C:\Users\[xyz]\git\[repo]
Output:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had Git installed, but it was only accessible from Git Bash (I had selected the first option below when installing). I reinstalled with the second option and it solved the issue:

[image]

Comment: Same here. And don't forget to reboot, otherwise the git command won't be available in the cmd.

Comment: reboot !!! haaaaaaaaa