# Im having issues when i try to install the bakeryswap libery on visual editor

Tags: npm

Im having trouble with installing npm i https://github.com/BakeryProject/bakery-swap-lib.git

this is the message i receive.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/BakeryProject/bakery-swap-lib.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: How is this c++ related? I'd guess git isn't installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install shows error with git not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473680/npm-install-shows-error-with-git-not-found)