# npm install returns syscall spawn git error

Tags: node.js, angular, git, npm, node-modules

I've tried to run npm install and faced these issues below

I've tried to clear cache with force command, install git and update node but nothing worked

here is the error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-01T11_56_42_862Z-debug.log
```

Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Hi, what was the npm install you used? according to the github repository, the install should be: npm install file-saver --save

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the following error while executing expo init command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450764/getting-the-following-error-while-executing-expo-init-command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnpm%5D+%22npm+ERR%21+enoent+undefined+ls-remote%22

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Make sure you have the GIT installed on your device and accessible globally. Try to type `git --version` in the CMD. If it returned that the command is not recognized and GIT already installed, then you need to add it to the PATH environment variable and make sure to try the command using a new CMD session

Comment: This is awesome. It worked for me. I installed git before install. Thanks.

Comment: I believe now git --version is needed. My system is iMac using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using a docker image, alpine version do not include `git`. Either switch to a non-alpine version (e.g. `node:16` instead of `node:16-alpine`) or install git in another way ([more info here](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/586)).

Answer (score 1):

Error means that 'git' is not recognized from the path/folder where you are trying to install.

1. For this, you can Add/Map environmental variables of Git.
2. Without mapping env variables, You can easily use Gitbash Terminal to get it installed easily. Example: In git bash terminal, run the command: npm install git+https://github.com/abc.git
   replace the git url with actual url of yours.

Answer (score -2):

Writing RUN instead of CMD may provide a solution.

```
RUN npm install
```

Comment: Hi, please explain how your answer may address the problem. There is an already accepted answer, very different