# npm dependencies installing error in Vuejs

Tags: git, vue.js, github, npm, npm-install

I know how to clone and run git repository but [Okuna](https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-www) git repository from Github is cloned successfully and when I install its dependencies.
This shows me an error.

I just simply install dependencies with the `npm install` comment.

**Error is:**

```
C:\Users\username\folder>npm install
npm WARN deprecated @xkeshi/vue-countdown@0.6.0: No longer maintainted, please use @chenfengyuan/vue-countdown
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-09T02_53_12_785Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What does that error say?

Comment: We have little chance of helping you if you do not at least give us the specific error messages.

Comment: I tried the npm install command in cmd but its thought error two error cd() never called and the second one is a git errort.

Comment: Do you have Git installed properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the following error while executing expo init command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450764/getting-the-following-error-while-executing-expo-init-command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+npm+ERR%21+enoent+undefined+ls-remote

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) is in your PATH, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148667/6309).

The best practice is to execute `npm install` from a `git bash` session, to be sure to be in an environment where Git will be active, even if not directly in your PATH.

Comment: @RohitNishad So you still have the issue? What is your path when you launch the npm command? Type `set PATH`.

Comment: bro, it's my 4 months ago question and I jump into Linux from windows or one more thing it's not very important for me at this time, I am so sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @RohitNishad No problem. I will leave my answer here, in case others have a similar problem to your question. You can leave it as is: it will help others.